# Topology and Shading Issue - Need Help with Redirecting Flow

Tags: modeling

I need help in correcting the edge flow of this Antique piece model TV. I have added that antenna Geo inside that face. After Connecting them Im now facing Shading issues and corners are NGON.

I've to solve 2 issues:

1. Optimize the Geo of overall Mesh on that face I:e the geo thats connecting whole mesh
2. I cant really understand the Edge flow of this

[image: Reference Pic]
[image: Topology in Blender]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7ooYnYJB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7ooYnYJB/)

Comment: @moonboots I have attached the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happens because the faces are not co-planar, therefore this shading between faces and this bad artefacts, it doesn't seem easy to make them co-planar as your topology is not very good, maybe you should simplify a lot, then select all these faces and flatten them on their axis, at the end use the *Weighted Normal* modifier, here a quick try, it still needs some cleaning etc:

[image]

Comment: Can you give me some suggestion how to improve the topology? Also I'm Observing its not quad based any more. Should i be concerened about it?
Thankyou for your contribution.

Comment: It's a bit hard to give suggestions, just make sure that the ngons are co-planar with the adjacent faces, it will prevent any bad shading, ngons are ok as long as they are co-planar

Comment: Thanks Moonbots. I've readjusted the topology and re-model internal geo with less detail. Its fine now

Comment: Oh OK great then   ;)